# How to add 'selected' on a option using 'setAttribute' with javascript

Tags: javascript

Fro example, I have this, and im trying to set by default option1, will be selected for default, how i can do it only using OPT.setAttribute(...,..):

```
 var SELECT = document.createElement('SELECT');

 var OPT1 = document.createElement('OPTION');
 OPT1.setAttribute('value', 0);

 var OPT2 = document.createElement('OPTION');
 OPT2.setAttribute('value', 0);

 OPT1.appendChild( document.createTextNode( 'option1' ) );
 OPT2.appendChild( document.createTextNode( 'option2' ) );

 SELECT.appendChild(OPT1);
 SELECT.appendChild(OPT2);
```

Im trying this :

```
OPT1.setAttribute('selected','true');
```

Obviusly dont work, thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```js
var SELECT = document.createElement('SELECT');
var OPT1 = document.createElement('OPTION');
OPT1.setAttribute('value', 0);

var OPT2 = document.createElement('OPTION');
OPT2.setAttribute('value', 0);
OPT2.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
// also you can set use .selected as a property 
// OPT2.selected = true;

OPT1.appendChild( document.createTextNode( 'option1' ) );
OPT2.appendChild( document.createTextNode( 'option2' ) );

SELECT.appendChild(OPT1);
SELECT.appendChild(OPT2);


document.getElementById('select').appendChild(SELECT);
```

```html
<div id="select"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Either you need to do `OPT1.setAttribute('selected','selected');` before `SELECT.appendChild(OPT1);` or you need to do `SELECT.selectedIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call( SELECT.children, OTP1);`

Comment: the order does not matter for the `setAttribute`, as OPT1 is still the same `option` domObject after the `appendChild`. but it matter for the `selectedIndex`